# R - Error when scraping: Chrome not reachable

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I’ve added a bit of code that aims to scrape Google + reviews, using R

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")

rmDr=rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
myclient= rmDr$client
myclient$navigate("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=queen%27s+hospital+romford&oq=queen%27s+hospitql+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5843j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x47d8a4ce4aaaba81:0xf1185c71ae14d00,1,,,")
pagesource= myclient$getPageSource()[[1]]


#Now I used the SelectorGadget tool to identify the relevant part I’d like to scrape

 reviews=read_html(pagesource) %>%
 html_nodes(".review-snippet") %>%
 html_text()
```

However once I run the code, I get an error message on the last part:

> chrome not reachable\n  (Session info: chrome=XX.X.XXXX.XXX)\n 
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=X.XX.XXXXX
>   (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX),platform=Windows NT
>   XX.X.XXXX x86_64)

I've tried to look into other stackoverflow posts for a solution, but haven't found one that works for R.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: See if my answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263875/im-trying-to-download-rselenium-for-r-v-3-5-but-it-says-the-following/51281660#51281660

Comment: The issue is with browser. May be try updating updating chrome or use Firefox.