# I'm trying to download RSelenium for R v 3.5 but it says the following

Tags: r, rselenium

```
install.packages("RSelenium")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mithu/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RSelenium’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

I also looked up on the blog and found:

```
install.packages("RSelenium", repos = "https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium.git")
```

which said the same error along with it couldn't reach the URL.

I also tried with R version 3.1.0, 3.1.3, 3.2.0 which gave me "wdman" & "binman" error and when I tried in the blog, it told me to upgrade R version.

Also, what does the "as 'lib' is unspecified" warning mean?

I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Look at: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/172

You can download RSelnium package by using:

```
library(devtools)
install_version("binman", version = "0.1.0", repos = "https://cran.uni-muenster.de/")
install_version("wdman", version = "0.2.2", repos = "https://cran.uni-muenster.de/")
install_version("RSelenium", version = "1.7.1", repos = "https://cran.uni-muenster.de/")
```